# Matplotlib figure, figsize with axis('equal')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to find an automatic way to set the figsize based on the size of each subplot in my figure after applying `Axes.axis('equal')`. What I obtain just by applying `Axes.axis('equal')` is here

image obtained with `Axes.axis('equal')` without further manipulations:
[image: image obtained with Axes.axis('equal') without further manipulations].

If I instead do NOT apply `Axes.axis('equal')`, this is what I obtain:

[image: this is what I obtain].

What I would like to obtain is something similar to:

[image: to this picture]

where I reset the figsize to remove the large vertical spacing between subtitle and the subplots.

Does anybody know how to automate this?

A possibility would be to get the dimensions of each subplot in inches, but I seem not to be able to find that info from the API.

Comment: This is a reasonable thing to want, but not available with Matplotlib currently.  You can look at axes_grid toolkit that has a simple way to do this.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thank you, that seems a good place where to start. Do you. know how to get the size of a subplot using that toolkit? Btw, is it part of Matplotlib?